# Log Jdbi interactions with database

Tags: jdbi, jdbi3, jdbi3-core

I've reviewed a couple of questions/answers here around the subject, but nothing works out-of-the-box. I've also read the [SqlLogger](https://jdbi.org/#_sqllogger) section in the official documentation, but still I can't find a way log/visualize what Jdbi (version `3.x`) "is doing" when it interacts with the database? — in a straightforward way.

> I'm aware Jdbi is using almost raw SQL, but it's always nice to be able to see what is it what the framework/library says it's doing for debugging purposes, etc.

I've tried pretty much any namespace starting from `org.jdbi` (within a `logback.xml` file), up until `trace` mode, but I just see something like this:

```sh
03-01-2021 19:52:26,656 |- TRACE in org.jdbi.v3.core.Jdbi:315 [reactor-http-epoll-2] - Jdbi [org.jdbi.v3.core.Jdbi@7a76fb45] obtain handle [org.jdbi.v3.core.Handle@725d5aec] in 0ms
03-01-2021 19:52:26,697 |- TRACE in org.jdbi.v3.core.Handle:187 [reactor-http-epoll-2] - Handle [org.jdbi.v3.core.Handle@725d5aec] released
```

Is there a way to do this these days?

Comment: I assume you have already looked at [`StatementContext`](https://jdbi.org/apidocs/org/jdbi/v3/core/statement/StatementContext.html) - accessible from your implementation of `SqlLogger`. If that is not suitable for your situation, maybe you could clarify where it falls short? Apart from the point that `ctx.getBinding().findForName()` is now deprecated ("_...keep your own state!_"), it has met my basic needs very well.

Comment: @andrewjames, what I'm looking for is a way to do what you can do with Hibernate's `show-sql`...thus, it's, a declarative way to do the same in Jdbi. I looked at that class, but I didn't get what you meant.

Comment: OK, understood. My approach is not declarative. I create my own implementation of `SQlLogger`: `public class MyAppSqlLogger implements SqlLogger` - and then I override `logAfterExecution(StatementContext ctx)`. In that method I have access to all the logging data I need: SQL statements, SQL parameters, execution times. It's a small class.

Comment: `SqlLogger` is the supported approach for this, if I understand the question right. Disclaimer: I developed it.

Answer (score 1):

Not a JDBI answer, but more generic way to see raw SQL is to use JDBC proxy like [P6Spy](https://p6spy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) or [datasource-proxy](http://ttddyy.github.io/datasource-proxy/docs/current/user-guide/).

P6Spy allows intercepting by either decorating `DataSource` or stub JDBC Driver (requires no code changes) and prints logs in format:

```
p6spy: #1617156635 | took 0ms | statement | connection 3|SELECT NOW()
```

Datasource-proxy only supports decorating `DataSource` and prints:

```
n.t.d.l.l.SLF4JQueryLoggingListener:
Name:, Time:0, Success:True
Type:Statement, Batch:False, QuerySize:1, BatchSize:0
Query:["SELECT NOW()"]
Params:[]
```